# Can a level creator set the world record on their own level?

Tags: super-mario-maker-2

If a level creator plays their own level and beats the best time record, will the game let the level creator set the world record on their own level?

Comment: Whilst it's impossible for a creator to set the World Record (using the same account), you can see the clear time for a level, which shows you the time it took when the creator uploaded the level. This can potentially be lower than the World Record.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently no.

As different [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MarioMaker/comments/c7oguc/how_do_i_see_how_long_it_took_me_to_beat_my_own/) users state, Nintendo developers don't want the level maker to outshine other players.

This was also [true for first SMM](https://www.reddit.com/r/MarioMaker/comments/4b1lyg/what_about_personal_best_time_records_in_selfmade/).